# Select all is not working in golaong gorm

Tags: mysql, json, go, crud, go-gin

I'm using gin framework and trying do crud operation using grom.I'm trying to get data from MYSQL database. i have db.go to get database instances, some controllers to each table and models
i have a model like this

```
    type Campaigns struct {

        ID                     int       `json:"id" form:"id" gorm:"column:CampaignID"`
        UserID                 int       `json:"userId" form:"userId" gorm:"column:UserID"`
        Name                   string    `json:"name" form:"name" gorm:"column:Name"`
        StartDate              time.Time `json:"start" form:"start" gorm:"column:StartDate"`
        EndDate                time.Time `json:"end" form:"end" gorm:"column:EndDate"`
        Customer               string    `json:"customer" form:"customer" gorm:"column:Customer"`
        CustomerID             int       `json:"customerId" form:"customerId" gorm:"column:CustomerID"`
        ImpressionsCounter     int       `json:"ImpressionsCounter" form:"ImpressionsCounter" gorm:"column:ImpressionsCounter"`
        MaxImpressions         int       `json:"maxImpressions" form:"maxImpressions" gorm:"column:MaxImpressions"`
        CurrentSpend           float64   `json:"currentSpend" gorm:"column:CurrentSpend"`
        MaxSpend               float64   `json:"maxSpend" form:"maxSpend" gorm:"column:MaxSpend"`
        Active                 bool      `json:"active" form:"active" gorm:"column:Active"`
        Created                time.Time `json:"created" gorm:"column:DateCreated"`
        Updated                time.Time `json:"updated" gorm:"column:DateCreated"`
}
```

this is a one controller I'm using

```
    package controllers
import (
    "time"

  "github.com/op/go-logging"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "../models"
)

var log = logging.MustGetLogger("AsAPI")

type AsController struct {
    DB gorm.DB
}

func (ac *AsController) SetDB(d gorm.DB) {
    ac.DB = d
    ac.DB.LogMode(true)
}


// Get all table
func (ac *AsController) ListTable(c *gin.Context) {

    var results []models.Campaigns
  err := ac.DB.Find(&results)

    if err != nil {
        log.Debugf("Error when looking up Table, the error is '%v'", err)
        res := gin.H{
                "status": "404",
                "error": "No Table found",
        }
        c.JSON(404, res)
        return
    }
    content := gin.H{
                        "status": "200",
            "result": "Success",
            "Table": results,
        }

  c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  c.JSON(200, content)
}
```

To get database connection I'm using

```
package controllers
import (
    "time"

  "github.com/op/go-logging"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "../models"
)

var log = logging.MustGetLogger("AdsAPI")

type AsController struct {
    DB gorm.DB
}

func (ac *AsController) SetDB(d gorm.DB) {
    ac.DB = d
    ac.DB.LogMode(true)
}
```

and I'm using following routs

```
ac := controllers.AdsController{}
ac.SetDB(dc.GetDB())


// Get a Ads resource
router := gin.Default()

router.GET("/table", ac.ListTables)
```

when i run this I'm getting following error

```
(/api/controllers/table.go:30) 
[2016-03-23 09:56:39]  [0.99ms]  SELECT  * FROM `tables`  
2016/03/23 09:56:39 Error when looking up tables, the error is '&{0xc8202140e0 sql: Scan error on column index 3: unsupported driver -> Scan pair: []uint8 -> *time.Time 1 <nil> 0xc82022f860 0xc82022f7c0 0xc82021e140 2 {0xc8201fb4a0} <nil> false  map[] map[]}'
[GIN] 2016/03/23 - 09:56:39 | 404 |    1.153811ms | 127.0.0.1 |   GET     /table
```

what is the reason for this error ? help me to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in the driver documentation
https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support:

> The default internal output type of MySQL DATE and DATETIME values is []byte which allows you to scan the value into a []byte, string or sql.RawBytes variable in your programm.
>
> However, many want to scan MySQL DATE and DATETIME values into time.Time variables, which is the logical opposite in Go to DATE and DATETIME in MySQL. You can do that by changing the internal output type from []byte to time.Time with the DSN parameter parseTime=true. You can set the default time.Time location with the loc DSN parameter.
>
> Alternatively you can use the NullTime type as the scan destination, which works with both time.Time and string / []byte.

Comment: ok i tried another application that doesn't have any DATETIME values but only have int and string. I got the same error..

Answer (score -3):

Are you ever actually opening the database here? I don't see an actual Open() call in there at all...